# How to create an ipfs CID with paths?

Tags: ipfs

How do I upload data to IPFS such that they are all accessible via a base CID? For example the CID `ipfs://bafybeihpjhkeuiq3k6nqa3fkgeigeri7iebtrsuyuey5y6vy36n345xmbi` on its own does not load any content but suffixed with a certain sub-path like `0` or `23` it will load a distinct document: `ipfs://bafybeihpjhkeuiq3k6nqa3fkgeigeri7iebtrsuyuey5y6vy36n345xmbi/23`. Also I'd be curious to learn how this works. I'm sorry if I'm getting some of the terminology wrong I'm still quite new to IPFS.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

IPFS allows the uploading of directories. The root CID without a path is how you address the entire folder and the path just fetches some sub-document. These have their own CID but can be also indirectly be accessed via parent CID and a connected path.